# Find all $w \in G_{28}$ such that $1 + w^2 + w^4 + w^6 =0$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

We can at once discard $w=1$ since it doesn't verify the equation.

We notice that

$$1 + w^2 + w^4 + w^6 =0 \ \iff \\ w^4 + w^6 = (-1)(1+w^2)$$

hence, we can square both sides **(can we?, are we losing solutions?)**,

$$w^8 + 2w^{10} + w^{12} = w^4 + 2w^2 + 1 \ \iff \\ (w^4)^2 (1+2w^2+w^4) = 1+2w^2+w^4$$

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is an integral domain, we know that either $1+2w^2+w^4 = 0$ or $(w^4)^2 = 1$.

We also know that

$$ 1+2w^2+w^4 = 0 \iff w^2 =-1 \\  (w^4)^2 = 1 \iff w^4 = \pm 1$$

But $w^2 =-1$ only if $w=\pm i$ and $w^4 = 1$ only if $w\in G_4 \subset G_{28}$; either way, $G_4 \setminus \{1\}$ is a solution.

On the other hand, $w^4 = -1$ only if $w^2 = \pm i$. But $w^2 \in G_{14}$ and $G_{14} \cap \{\pm i\} = \emptyset$ (since $4$ is not a divisor of $14$).

**So our solution is $G_4 \setminus \{1\}$, right?**

Comment: What is w? Here

Comment: Note:  $1+w^2+w^4+w^6=(w^8-1)/(w^2-1)$

Comment: Please define $G_n$

Comment: "Are we losing solutions?" No, you'd be creating false solutions, if anything. If you start with $a = b$ and square both sides, you are merging the possibilities of $a = b$ or $a = -b$ together, and your final solution set will satisfy one possibility or the other (but possibly not the one that you wanted).

Comment: so by squaring you're bringing in $w=-1$ even though that isn't a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The systematic way is to compute the gcd of the polynomials $1 + w^2 + w^4 + w^6$ and $1-w^{28}$. This gcd is $w^2+1$ and so the solution is $w=\pm i$. This set is $G_4 \setminus G_2$.

Comment: Check with [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd(1%2Bw%5E2%2Bw%5E4%2Bw%5E6,1-w%5E28)).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
1 + w^{2} + w^{4} + w^{6} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (1+w^{2}) + w^{4}(1+w^{2}) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (1+w^{4})(1+w^{2}) = 0
\end{align*}

Comment: you also have to realize that if $w^4=-1$ then $w^{28}\ne1$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\zeta=\exp(2i\pi/28)$.

Then $(\zeta^n)^8=1 \iff 7|n,\;$ and   $(\zeta^n)^2=1\iff14|n$.

So  $1+(\zeta^n)^2+(\zeta^n)^4+(\zeta^n)^6=\dfrac{(\zeta^n)^8-1}{(\zeta^n)^2-1}=0  \iff 7|n$ and not $14|n \iff \zeta^n=\pm\, i .$